# How to get values from dropdown box in MVC knockout binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, dropdownbox

This is hpw i'm filing my dropdown box

```js
$.ajax({
            url: "CheckinRelatedMember",
            type: "POST",
            data: { ClubId: localStorage.getItem("ClubId"), memacctno: localStorage.getItem("memacctno") },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var RelatedMembers;
                RelatedMembers = JSON.parse(data.CheckinRelatedMemberResult);
                self.RelMembers(RelatedMembers);
```

How to get Option value from knockout dropdown list. I had successfully binded an dropdown box. but my problem is while i retrieve value from   tag. option value unable to appear.

```js
function FillCheckInRec() {
            submemacctno = document.getElementById("RelateMem")[0].value;

i need to pass selected option value to FillCheckInRec() method.
```

```html
<p>
                    <label>
                        Select Member
                    </label>
                    <select id="RelateMem" class="input-medium" data-bind="options: RelMembers, optionsText:'Name',optionvalue:'AcctNo', value: 'AcctNo'"></select>
                </p>
```

But while i pass select value into FillCheckinRec() method, value comes like this (""). how to get AcctNo From dropdown list. Please Help Me!

Comment: modify this  value: 'AcctNo' to value: AcctNo . remove quotes & declare `AcctNo ` as observable

Comment: Thanks for your comment. i'm facing same problem.

Comment: alright there are few errors(optionsValue not optionsvalue) corrected those and posted a answer please check

Comment: try submemacctno = $("#RelateMem").val() to retrieve value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**view:**

```
<p>
    <label>Select Member</label>
    <select data-bind="options: RelMembers, optionsText:'Name',optionsValue:'AccNo', value:AcctNo"></select>
</p>
<hr/>
<b><label data-bind="text:AcctNo"></label></b>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.RelMembers = ko.observableArray();
    self.AcctNo = ko.observable();

    $.ajax({
         url: '/echo/json/',
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            var RelatedMembers = [{
                'Name': 'One',
                    'AccNo': 1
            }, {
                'Name': 'Two',
                    'AccNo': 2
            }, {
                'Name': 'Three',
                    'AccNo': 3
            }]
            self.RelMembers(RelatedMembers);
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26571/)**

Comment: While i hard code like above codes, it works fine. but my dropdown box is dynamic, Value is unable to bind. and it shows like this <option value>Name</option>, but i need like this <option value=Acctno (i.e 1)>Name</option>

Comment: check the update one thumb note if something is working static it will dynamic too i believe (mostly) . let me know

Comment: still facing issue share the data you getting here  `data.CheckinRelatedMemberResult` .

Comment: Yes, i got data in data.CheckinRelatedMemberResult. those data's are binned in dropdown box. while i retrieve value unable to get

Comment: please post what is the data you getting there . check my update i am making ajax call to fill data still it works fine .

Comment: have you modified `optionsvalue` to `optionsValue` ? please read the comments properly .

Comment: Yes, i had changed it.

Comment: then it should work . you can see the working fiddle posted .

Answer (score 0):

Well I got fix this issue, Here is my code.

```js
var submemacctno = $("#RelateMem").val();
```

```html
 <select id="RelateMem" class="input-medium" data-bind="options: RelMembers, optionsText:'Name',optionsValue:'AcctNo', value:'AcctNo'"></select>
```

This is my HTML Code, Rest of everything are same.
 Thank You!

Comment: `$("#RelateMem").val()` and `AcctNo` will have same value . don't mix jquery when ko does the job easily

Comment: Yes, Now i had Cleared about that.Okay MR.Super Cool, Thanks for your support.